# Simple Past vs. Present Perfect in a list

Tags: grammar, writing-style, present-perfect, simple-past

Consider these sentences:

(Simple Past)

> I accepted the cars, hated the planes, ignored the boats, and romanticized the trains.

(Present Perfect)

> I have accepted the cars, have hated the planes, have ignored the boats, and have romanticized the trains.

Why does the second one sound so strange/artificial to my ears?

Comment: What about it sounds strange to your ears?

Comment: Because you have repeated all the auxiliary verbs instead of deleting them by conjunction reduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds odd because you repeated the auxiliary verb "have" so many times. You would normally just write:

> I have accepted the cars, hated the planes, ignored the boats, and romanticized the trains.

Of course, it's now ambiguous as to whether the "have" governs the verb "hated" or not, but I think most people would interpret "hated" as a present perfect, not as a simple past. To illustrate this, consider two examples:

> 1. I have ordered food and eaten it.
> 2. I have ordered food and ate it.

(2) is unidiomatic, bordering on ungrammatical. So normally one would interpret the "have" as governing both conjuncts. This is because the order of the conjuncts in such cases usually reflects temporal ordering, and simple past events typically do not happen after present perfect ones.